# How to tell swagger that particular response has no response type except status code?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm creating swagger document for ASP.net API. I want to show in swagger that there is no response (other than status code) for any given status code. I have following attributes on my method:

[image]

This gives me following result in swagger:

[image]

As you can see status codes 200 and 500  does not have response type and this is what I want. But 401 has unnecessary response type. I want to get rid of it. The same is true for all other status codes (except 200 and 500). I've tried adding EmptyResult but this still produces empty brackets as a response:

[image]

[image]

Do you maybe know how I can configure this? I'm using Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions of ASP.NET CORE errors will produce an instance of [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can disable it in ur `Startup` using the following code:

```cs
services
    .AddControllers() //or addMvc() for older projects
    //below the important part to add
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
    });
```